# ArrayList Duplicate Removal

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public static void deleteDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list){
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        set.add(list.get(i));
    }

    newList.addAll(set);
    return newList;
}
```

My input for this is the following:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
3, 2, 4, 1, 5
```

Can anyone explain why this is out of order?

Comment: Set data structure does not maintain order. But if you want sorted then you can use Tree Set.

Comment: @ShivamKalra you mean `HashSet`, because [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) does.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, I mean any set data structure. Linked Hashset keeps a Linked List internally to keep order.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Thanks I didn't know that about HashSets.

Comment: LinkedHashSet maintains the order the elements were inserted in. TreeSet order the elements according to their natural order.

Comment: @ShivamKalra `Set` is the interface, and `HashSet` is an implementation. Next time choose the right words :).

Comment: Coincidentally, both would give `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` here because of the input order.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza In computer science `Set` is a data structure.

Comment: @ShivamKalra yes, but this is Java, so you can't say *`Set` data structure does not maintain order.* when there is a `Set` implementation that does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `HashSet` for [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.

Also, remember to [always program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197):

```
public static void deleteDuplicates(List<String> list){
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: @user1327636 don't forget to program interface oriented, not to class implementations (check the link provided in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the HashSet class documentation:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more effecient way but here's an idea for an n^2 algorithm for removal

```
public static void deleteDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list){
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

boolean exists = false;
String str = list.get(i);
for (int j = 0; j < newList.size(); j++){
if (newList.get(j).compareTo(str)==0){
exists = true;
break;
}
}
if (!exists) newList.add(str);
}
return newList;
}
```